# query Date picker year selecting current year on first time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using a `JQuery UI datepicker`. I have set the date range of `-80:-18.` The datepicker shows date range correctly. But the problem here is, when I first select any date from calender it is showing the `current year` instead.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        YearRange : "-80Y:-18Y"
    });
```

On load of the screen its showing **year** as `1934`. If I select any **date** from calender its showing `27/01/2014`. If I change the year from drop down, its working as expected. Only on **load of the page** I am facing this problem. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem 
here is code, i hope it help you :
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        YearRange : "-80Y:-18Y",
        maxDate": "-18Y"
    });

Regards
Saleha

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

just include this code on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#id').val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", new Date()));
});
```